# shared hosting website optimization (US server)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, optimization

i have a hosting server on godaddy. i have the economic plan which is a shared one for my current project (i have a tight budget until i get traffic and mnoey)

i am using linux and i have data in my databases (pages, user etc...). when i display `/folder/pagex/` i rewrite it internally to `rewriterule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?f=$1&p=$2` then after is query the database, get the data and generate the webpage.

everything works great but obviously it has to go to a process

1. get the page from the .htaccess -> query the database -> generate -> display

i would like to know if there's a faster way to execute this? like skipping the database query some how but still displaying the page

Comment: maybe you have to go to a VPS solution and then you can install memcache for example

Comment: Not sure that this merits a -1 as it is a perfectly valid Q, and I have to dissent with the view that going to VPS is _the_ answer to all performance issues.

Comment: thanks bookofzeus ill look into this

Comment: @TerryE then what do you suggest?

Comment: Sorry Trent, I was writing up my answer as below

Comment: Does GoDaddy use an opcode-cache such as APC or eAccelerator? If not, move to a plan that does (are they generally offered on shared hosting? I dunno).

Comment: Make sure you run your site through YSlow or similar too - you can get a huge speed increase by reorganising your asset files.

Comment: @halfer, shared hosting services like GoDaddy's provide UID-based access control so that indvidual accounts can protect their content from cohosted 3rd-party accounts.  This means they can't use mod_php, but use either suPHP or equiv.  This effectively prevents PHP Opcode caching.  Each request for a scripted resource has to take the image activation and script compilation hit.

Comment: Ouch! I'd say that adding that would be a huge source of improvement, and easy too - which is presumably why @BookOfZeus recommended a VPS :). Edit: OP, VPS machines are really cheap these days. There is loads of power in my 512MB/10GB play server, and I pay 5GBP/month. That will easily cope with a low-traffic site, and permit these sort of customisations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is an awful lot you can do.  I run my blog on a LAMP/suPHP-based shared hosting service, Webfusion rather than GoDaddy, but their overall implementation architectures are pretty similar: a load-balancing IP switch fronting onto a LAMP server farm which then has switched 1Gb interconnect back to NAS infrastructure for the user directory space and a D/B farm to operate the databases.  (And yes, I also have an Amazon EC2 micro instance.)

This type of service offering is low cost, scalable and does not involve the account holder in known how to configure and administer a cloud VM.  I also hold all of my content and configuration in a backend D/B.  My blog has an average page load time (measured by Chome Pagespeed) of 200-500mSec and [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) score of 99/100.

So yes in an suPHP configuration, each script involves a PHP image activation which normally adds ~100mSec to request times ([this article](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-44) explains how to benchmark this for your own service), but when you do Pagespeed timing of transactions from the end-user perspective, it is usually poor caching and lack of compression that dogs performance.  Once you've sorted out that, then there's the image start-up which you can't avoid for dynamic content -- unless as Zeus suggests, you move to a dedicated VM + mod_php5 + Xcache/APC.

The next big hit is the I/O overhead of marshalling and reading in all of the script files, and this can add a few seconds on the first request when these are not in a VFAT cache, but again I discuss mitigation in my blog articles.

The PHP compilation time itself and the script execution time are in the noise -- unless you've done something *really* dumb, like doing full table scans or joins on the same for large tables that aren't properly indexed.

Anyway, I've written a bunch of articles that address this sort of topic for developers just like you.  Read them, and I hope that you find them useful.  Please come back here with any more Qs, but remember to keep them focused; also make sure that you provide the supporting info and don't use this as a substitute for reasonable levels of research.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't, because it's getting the data from a database, maybe using Cloudflare and CDN can improve your page load time (I think that is what you mean).

Good luck

Comment: CDNs are generally expensive - so might not be good if the OP is on a budget. That said, if he is using a popular JS library, he can use the resources on Google's CDN for free!

Comment: I use maxcdn and its not that expensive.

Comment: OK, great. How does the charging structure work - do you pay by the GB? (I should think approx costs would be interesting for the OP).

Comment: Yes, you can pay per TB or a month quota for 5TB. The first TB is 70USD (I got it on 35 with a coupon on retailmenot) and the others are a little more expensive. I haven't used even 1 GB ;)